# Specifying An External Log4j2.xml File Per WAR

Tags: java, log4j2

I have an application that deploys 4 separate war files, each requiring a customized log4j2.xml file (this makes using `-Dlog4j.configurationLocation=_____` impractical).

What I need to do is to be able to configure these on a per-WAR basis, in a filesystem location named `/application/config/`. This should be possible via the servlet initializer as such:

```java
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // other code
        servletContext.setInitParameter("log4jConfiguration", "file:/application/config/log4j2-module1.xml");
        // other code
    }
```

I have added `log4j-web` to the POM, but I'm still having no luck. I've looked through all of the other people asking similar questions, and nothing. I've also created a Listener specifically to initialize log4j, and still nothing.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? This is a Spring (but not Spring Boot) application, so I can't just make a change to `application.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`web-fragment.xml`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/release-2.x/log4j-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/web-fragment.xml) from `log4j-web`, you'll notice that it is ordered before any other fragments. This is intentional: logging is usually the first service you need to initialize. That explains why your `WebApplicationInitializer`s are executed too late.

To configure multiple web applications I would use "convention over configuration" and add a file called `log4j2<context name>.xml` in either the `WEB-INF` folder or the application's classpath.

The context name is the first non empty value between:

1. The `log4jContextName` servlet parameter,
2. The value of `<display-name>`,
3. The context path.

If you want to follow a different convention, you can add a `log4j2.configurationFile` property to a `log4j2.component.properties` file on the application's classpath.